# creating dialog box similar to facebook?

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook

I want to create dialog bar like facebook's dialog box..
Because if user click for dialog box, don't exit the site. User click dialogbox neccesary to open same window..

Shorly--> Facebook's dialog boxes..

How can i do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made something like that... http://jsfiddle.net/uCKmj/

Comment: I made it for one of my apps on FB recently, wanted to feel like the real thing, it was done quickly, so you can modify it... shorty, you put id in rel attribute on anchor, and it will be shown on click. Accept as correct answer if you think so. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

check [this](http://choosedaily.com/1178/15-jquery-popup-modal-dialog-plugins-tutorials/) list it has many examples of dialogs you can use
also theres a plug in called [facebox](http://defunkt.io/facebox/) its very similar to facebook

Answer (score 1):

Try jqueryUI dialog function - http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog